# get recent comments of a particular category

Tags: comments

I am using `get_comments('status=approve&number=5')` to display recent comments in my wordpress sidebar. I need to display the recent comments of a particular category. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this link](http://blog.ashfame.com/2011/04/get-comments-category-wordpress/), there is the following code that addresses your question:

```
// Posts per page setting
$ppp = get_option('posts_per_page'); // either use the WordPress global Posts per page setting or set a custom one like $ppp = 10;
$custom_offset = 0; // If you are dealing with your custom pagination, then you can calculate the value of this offset using a formula

// category (can be a parent category)
$category_parent = 3;

// lets fetch sub categories of this category and build an array
$categories = get_terms( 'category', array( 'child_of' => $category_parent, 'hide_empty' => false ) );
$category_list =  array( $category_parent );
foreach( $categories as $term ) {
 $category_list[] = (int) $term->term_id;
}

// fetch posts in all those categories
$posts = get_objects_in_term( $category_list, 'category' );

$sql = "SELECT comment_ID, comment_date, comment_content, comment_post_ID
 FROM {$wpdb->comments} WHERE
 comment_post_ID in (".implode(',', $posts).") AND comment_approved = 1
 ORDER by comment_date DESC LIMIT $ppp OFFSET $custom_offset";

$comments_list = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

if ( count( $comments_list ) > 0 ) {
 $date_format = get_option( 'date_format' );
 echo '<ul>';
 foreach ( $comments_list as $comment ) {
 echo '<li>Comment: '.substr( $comment->comment_content, 0, 50 ).'..<br />'.date( $date_format, strtotime( $comment->comment_date ) ).'<br />Post: <a href="'.get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID ).'">'.get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID ).'</a></li>';
 }
 echo '</ul>';
} else {
 echo '<p>No comments</p>';
}
?>
```